# Angular js sort a list of items based on few conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular noob here

I have an angular app in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qhiYTvwRHt4wqmliF0V?p=preview).

How do i sort the list displayed here using angular such that the course with the flag always stays on the top and the remaining items are sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the orderBy.

Change your ngRepeat to this:

```
<a ng-repeat="prog in programs | orderBy:'academic_program.program_title' | orderBy:'primary_program':true" href="#" ng-click="display.addprogram = false" class="list-group-item">
```

Here's the modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PJBvf5MyGe3ggD2uFkKf?p=preview

Comment: hi can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965379/angular-js-toggle-checkbox-function-to-disable-checkboxes